# Поиск использования __init__ для dataclass в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, dataclass

Если использовать dataclass в python, то у классов можно пропустить создание **init** метода. Но вместе с этим становится неудобно искать места, где создаются экземпляры этого класса используя IDE PyCharm.

Например у обычного класса выделив **init** метод и нажав Ctrl + ЛКМ (или Ctrl + B) отобразятся места, где создаются экземпляры этого класса (если этих мест несколько) или сразу перемещает на место создания экземпляра (если найдено только одном место).
Но из-за отсутствия **init** у dataclass такой способ не получится использовать.

Если нажать на Ctrl + B по имени класса, PyCharm начинает искать все места использования класса и выводит места не только создания экземпляра, но и места где у переменной задан тип с этим классом (а таких мест может быть десятки).

Сейчас я использую поиск по проекту указав название класса и круглую скобку, например "ClassName(".

Может я что-то упускаю и есть более удобный способ?